# Postgres как показать адрес базы из другой директории

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Всем доброго времени!
подскажите пожалуйста, решил познать postgres.
Устанавливаю, но подключиться могу только к файлам баз самого postgres, то есть к тем которые создаю в терминале.

Как быть , если хочу подключится к уже имеющемуся файлу базы данных?
менял директорию postgres.conf тогда выпадает ошибка, что не может соединиться, устанавливал несколко раз уже,что сделать чтобы показать файл другой базы.

import psycopg2

try:
con=psycopg2.connect(dbname='db',user='postgres',password='postgres',host='127.0.0.1',port='5432' )
print('Connect')
con.close()
except:
print("No connect")
вот по такому примеру пытаюсь подключится, если создана через терминал, все получается иначе ошибка.

Comment: никак. инстанс постгреса работает только со своим каталогом данных. для использования каталога с другим кластером, надо запускать постгрес с указанием каталога PGDATA с ключем -D

Comment: это когда  initdb -D /адрес к файлу?
я пробовал так делать не получается

Comment: Нет. запускать постгрес указывая путь postgres -D /path/to/PGDATA. initdb это инициализация кластера. И у постгреса нет "файла базы". Там структура каталогов-файлов